# Determine reason for required Android permissions (assumed cause: AdMob)

Tags: android, admob, android-permissions

I've created an Android app in two flavours:

- one payed-for, [ad-free version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.zielkes.sudokudojo.pro)
- one [free version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.zielkes.sudokudojo.lite), which uses AdMob

Both versions are functionally identical and use the same libs, AdMob being the one exception.

The payed-for version **does not require any permissions** and the permission overview shown in Google Play reflect this.

The free version declares two required permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

These are needed by AdMob as [described here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#modify_the_manifest_file).

Now the free version lists three more required permissions in Google Play (which I tried to translate from German):

- Identity
- Coarse grained location
- Fotos/Media (**!**)

As the payed-for version differs only in not using AdMob, it has to be the cause for these permissions.

My questions are:

- Where are they declared?
- Are they really necessary (especially the Fotos one)?
- If not - how can I get rid of them?

Thanks a bunch

Nudelsuppe

### Error found

It was my own fault, I had

```
liteCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
```

instead of

```
liteCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

in my gradle build file. The not-needed services parts (like maps, identity, ...) required the other permissions.

Thanks for your answers, they set me on the right track. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in the `manifest-merger-log`file at

```
/app/build/outputs/logs
```

You will find entries like this one:

```
uses-permission#android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
   ADDED from com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0:22:5
```

In this case it tells that the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission was added to your Manifest by Google Play Services.

Comment: Thanks, that has helped a lot. I now know, that the coarse location is required by `uses-permission#android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
ADDED from com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0:23:5` - now I have to find out, whether (and how) I can get rid of the parts of the Google Play services that AdMob does not require...

Comment: Ok, the individual services are listed [here](http://inteist.com/individual-google-play-services/). If I find a list of those that AdMob really needs, I'll post them here.

Answer (score 0):

They are declared in manifest file. 
And if you need to access those features; yes its necessary.